# iOS SwiftUI Custom Tab bar view hiding when navigating between UIViewControllerRepresentable

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui, uikit, storyboard

I have a custom TabBar view which consists of a `Group` of UIViewControllerRepresentables that are presnted when the `TabRouter` state changes accordingly.

The state is changed in the `MenuView` which just changed an internal `@Published` var within the `TabRouter` that holds the `viewState`

```
struct TabBarView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var router: TabRouter
    
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geo in
            VStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 0) {
                Group {
                    switch router.viewState {
                    case .state1:
                        LegacyVCRepresentable1()
                    case .state2:
                        LegacyVCRepresentable2()
                    case .state3:
                        LegacyVCRepresentable3()
                    case .state4:
                        LegacyVCRepresentable4()
                    }
                }
                .frame(maxHeight: .infinity)
                
                MenuView()
                    .frame(width: geo.size.width, height: geo.size.height/12)
            }
        }
        .ignoresSafeArea(edges: .top)
    }
}
```

My problem here is that those legacy ViewControllers that I am presenting within this SwiftUI view is that they are storyboards and each one has different segues that navigate deeper within the navigation stack inside each one of them (UINavigationController transitions).

Is it possible for me to get some sort of callback when the views are being navigated deeper, so I can hide the `MenuView` when it shouldn't be seen?

OR shall I have to pass in some sort of callback variable like:

```
     case .state1:
         LegacyVCRepresentable1(onNavigated: onNavigated)

func onNavigated() {
    self.hidesMenuView = true
}
```

And handle all those parts myself? Maybe someone has faced a similar issue and has a more elegant solution?

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT 1:**

I will try to implement `UINavigationControllerDelegate` in the view controllers, and call the `onNavigated` method when `navigationController(willShow:)` is called. Will update.